# How i can get selected info from json array?

Tags: php, json

i have printed json array, it loks like:

```
array (size=1)
  '2013-04-02' => 
    array (size=13)
      0 => 
        array (size=8)
          'date' => string '2013-04-02' (length=10)
          'sign' => int 0
          'slant' => string 'Generic' (length=7)
          'rating' => int 3
          'interp' => string 'We are eager to bring excitement into our lives today but other obligations prevent us from acting irresponsibly. The buzz from all the action-packed Aries planets keeps the energy jumping, but the Moon trudges into emotionally resistant Capricorn at 1:35 am EDT to set a serious tone to the day as we go about our business. Meanwhile, we can feel the weight of stern Saturn pushing away pleasure as it forms a difficult aspect with sweet Venus.' (length=445)
          'sms_interp' => string '' (length=0)
          'keyword' => string 'obligations' (length=11)
          'subject_line' => string 'We are eager to bring excitement into our lives ...' (length=51)
      1 => 
        array (size=8)
          'date' => string '2013-04-02' (length=10)
          'sign' => int 1
          'slant' => string 'Generic' (length=7)
          'rating' => int 2
          'interp' => string 'You are growing tired of your current responsibilities and are ready for a change of pace. You feel as if you have been working hard enough and now you are eager to take a break. Unfortunately, you may have to put off the fun and games a while longer while you fulfill the promises you already made to yourself and others. Thankfully, you'll really be able to let loose once you don't have unfulfilled obligations still hanging over your head.' (length=443)
          'sms_interp' => string '' (length=0)
          'keyword' => string 'commitments' (length=11)
          'subject_line' => string 'You are growing tired of your ...' (length=33)
```

How i can get information from needful array, for example: 0 -> interp?

Comment: `data["2013-04-02"][0].interp` (in Javascript)

Comment: In PHP? Or JavaScript? Why is it tagged JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't read too much into json. it's a data encapsulation format. You don't deal with a "json array". There's no such thing. There's a json **STRING**, which you decode into a native data structure. e.g.

```
$json = "... your raw json text here ...";
$data = json_decode($json, true); // true to force an array, instead of object.

echo $data['2013-04-02'][0]['interp'];
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be json_decode($json, true); or is it like that by default.